# QMAKE_MSC_VER isn't set

Tags: qt, qt5.5

After I changed my Qt Version from 5.5.1 to 5.12.0 I get following message while I try to build any project:

`msvc-version.conf loaded but QMAKE_MSC_VER isn't set`

I selected the Qt 5.12.0 MSVC2017 32bit Kit instead of the Qt 5.5.1 (msvc 2013) Kit.

Does anybody know the reason for this message and could explain me how I should fix it?

Answer (score 52):

Try removing any .qmake.stash files in your projects. This fixed this same issue for me when building QT from source after previously building with a different target.

Comment: take note that the stash file is invisible. that took me some time to figure out. deleting it worked.

Comment: if removing .qmake.stash didn't work (that was the case when I tried it), try running `qmake` with the option `-nocache`.

Comment: I just ran into this AGAIN, googled, found this answer AGAIN, and saw my own note above. This time, i found the invisible .qmake.stash file TWO LEVELS UP from my project file??!?

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this error message after returning to a project I hadn't worked on in a year.
I solved it by deleting the project's `.pro.user` file. (It seems to have been looking for a build kit I had gotten rid of at some point in the year.)

Answer (score 2):

Open `msvc-version.conf` (in my case in `C:\Qt\Qt5.12.8\5.12.8\msvc2017_64\mkspecs\common`)

add

```
QMAKE_MSC_VER = 1929
```

at the beginning (for VS2019).

Answer (score 0):

In older Qt versions, like Qt 5.6, which is last version that allows v2.1 of LGPL license.

Such thing as `QMAKE_MSC_VER` does not exist.

Simply create it, like:

- Open `mkspecs/common/msvc-desktop.conf` file (from to Qt-sources) in editor.
- Find:

  ```
  unset(MSC_VER)
  ```
- Replace it with below and done:

  ```
  QMAKE_MSC_VER = $$MSC_VER
  unset(MSC_VER)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If your intended compiler isn't MSVC to begin with, but rather MinGW, be sure you have the correct project configuration selected! :)